# How to have access to an inherited method in C#?

Tags: c#

Am I missing any concept about inheritance? I am trying to call a method that is in a child class but it doesn't work.

This is what I have, so simple:

**Vuelo.cs**

```
 public class Vuelo
{
    private Aeronave _aeronave { get; set; }

    public Vuelo(string numero, Aeronave aeronave)
    {
        ValidarNumero(numero); // validates numero

        _aeronave = aeronave;
    }

    public string modelo_aeronave()
    {
        return _aeronave.model(); // This is where the error goes, .model()
    }

    public string RegistroAvion()
    {
        return _aeronave.Registration(); // This worked perfectly
    }
}
```

**Aeronave.cs**

```
 public class Aeronave
{
    private string _registration { get; set; }


    public Aeronave(string registration)
    {
        _registration = registration;
    }

    public string Registration()
    {
        return _registration;
    }

}
```

**Airbus319.cs** (the child class):

```
 public class AirbusA319 : Aeronave
{
    private string _model { get; set; }

    public AirbusA319(string model, string registro) : base(registro)
    {
        _model = model;

    }

    public string model()
    {
        return _model;
    }
}
```

I want to show up the *model* of the Airbus that is in `model()` like this:

```
Vuelo vuelo = new Vuelo("AB345", new AirbusA319("G-EUPT", "GG235"));
Console.WriteLine(vuelo.modelo_aeronave());
```

I can't find solutions in the internet, even in microsoft docs about inheritance.

Comment: `Vuelo` knows nothing about `Airbus319`. How can it call `model` method declared in `Airbus319`? Either move `model` into `Aeronave`, or don't use inheritance.

Comment: Why did it work in python? I did this in the same approach, and I was surprised that python recognized `.model()` that is stored in Airbus319.

Comment: You cant expect c# to behave similar to python, python supports multiple inheritance but to achieve that in c# we need to use interfaces.

Comment: @Manti_Core: How is this related to single/multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modify your classes as shown below. Aeronave should contain model (virtual or abstract) to be overridden in Airbus.

```
public abstract class Aeronave
{
    private string _registration { get; set; }


    public Aeronave(string registration)
    {
        _registration = registration;
    }

    public string Registration()
    {
        return _registration;
    }
     public abstract string model();

}
public class AirbusA319 : Aeronave
{
    private string _model { get; set; }

    public AirbusA319(string model, string registro) : base(registro)
    {
        _model = model;

    }

    public override string model()
    {
        return _model;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I should convert `public class Aeronave` into an abstract class in the first place?  `public abstract class Aeronave ` , because I am getting an error: `Abstract method in non-abstract class`

Comment: yes you can make it virtual, better you make the class abstract, I would prefer interface, because interface looks more obvious in constructor dependency injection.